# Injectivity radius of Exponential and curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

Define : [Injectivity radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Riemannian_and_metric_geometry#I) , [Exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_(Riemannian_geometry)#Definition)

This question is considered in Riemann manifold. I think the Injectivity radius is connect with curvature.

I guess the Injectivity radius can be controlled by curvature.I think there should be some function make the below inequality right.
$$
f(curvature)\leq \text{Injectivity radius} \leq  g(curvature)
$$

Is it right? Or there is other better conclusion ? What I should read about this question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such control. For example, for each $r_1, r_2 >0$, the torus

$$\{(r_1e^{i\theta_1}, r_2e^{i\theta_2} ): \theta_1, \theta_2 \in \mathbb R\} \in \mathbb C^2$$

has zero curvature, however by varying $r_1, r_2$, the injectivity radius can be made arbitrarily large/small.

What the curvature really control is the [conjugate locus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_points), which is a subset of the cut points.