# Smooth of $d(x_0,exp_x(v))$ and injectivity radius.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

According to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672678/injectivity-radius-of-exponential-and-curvature), the curvature can't control the injectivity radius. So, I don't know why support of $\varphi(v)$ need be small compared to maximum curvature? I think it should be compared to injectivity radius for keeping $f(x)$ is smooth.

Picture below is from the 210 page of this [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ajm/1154098947).

> [image]